# force react.js to load depenencies via ssl

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, playframework-2.0, reactjs

I have a Play framework app which handles sensitive data and so enforces SSL.

I'm building a frontend with React.js , but when I try to load

```
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I get the error

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://localhost:9443/react' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://dragon.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t39.3284-6/10173493_255140104677950_2108691993_n.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

How can I enforce that the transient dependencies are also loaded via https?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Facebook "CDN" for React doesn't work over HTTPS right now, sorry. You can instead use cdnjs:

http://cdnjs.com/libraries/react

Your script tags will look something like

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.11.1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.11.1/react.js"></script>
```